# How can I always show page numbers in new LibreOffice Writer documents?

Tags: libreoffice

I would like to make showing page numbers the default setting for new LibreOffice Writer documents.

Comment: I assume for new documents? You *could* make a right- click option in its launcher, to open a default template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a file with the page number showing and making that your default document template.

The steps are:

**Change the Default Document Template**

```
1. Make a new document with the page number showing.
2. Save this as a document template.
3. Import your new document template file into the Documents Templates.
    (Click) File -> New -> Template -> (click the Star to Import) -> Browse to
    your new template -> (Double Click the file)
4. Select this new Template in the "My Templates Section" and check Mark it for
    your default template.
```

**Resetting to the Default Default Template**

If for any reason you want to have the `Default Template` back the way it originally was use these steps:

```
File -> Templates -> Manage Templates -> (Click on the symbol to the right of
the magnifying glass) -> Reset Default Template -> (Click) Text Document -> (Click) Close.
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I accidentally created a [new template category](http://i.imgur.com/7a0NDwN.png). How can I delete it?

Comment: You can delete a category (template folder) with: `File -> Templates -> Manage -> (scroll until you see the category) -> (select it) -> (Click the delete Icon to the right of the Star)`

Comment: @RobertOrzanna Glad it worked!